# How do I write a superfactorial program?

Tags: java, factorial

> Write a program to calculate and print the super factorial of a number using a for loop. The factorial of a number is the product of all integers up to and including that number, so the factorial of 4 (written as 4!) is 4*3*2*1= 24.
>
> The super factorial is the product of all factorials up to and including that factorial.
>
> 4!!=4!*3!*2!*1!

I found "factorial" using the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class superfactorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        // number whose factorial to be found
        int number;
        // prompting input
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            number = input.nextInt();

        int factorial = factorial(number);

        System.out.printf("the factorial of %d is %d", number , factorial);
    }

    // method that calculates the factorial
    public static int factorial (int n){
        int output = 1; 
        for (int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
            output = output * i;                
        }
            return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `int` for this - it doesn't store large enough numbers.  You'll probably want to learn to use the `BigInteger` class.

Comment: i know, but my question is how to find the superfactorial or how to write the code for that

Comment: Are you saying you want someone to write the code for you?  It seems to me that if you can write a `factorial` method, you already know everything you need to know, to write a `superfactorial` method.  What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important line in your factorial method is this line:

```
output = output * i;
```

You multiply `output` by `i` where `i` is an integer that keeps increasing by one.

What's the difference between a superfactorial and a normal factorial? To evaluate a superfactorial, you multiply `output` not by `i`, but by the factorial of `i`, right?

So just do it! I have already explained the whole thing to you! Just create a new method called `superfactorial`, copy all the stuff from the factorial method and change this line:

```
output = output * i;
```

to this:

```
output = output * factorial(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider 4! = 4x3x2x1, you can see that there are 4 numbers in the decomposition. in general there will be n numbers in the decomposition of n! (n(n-1)(n-2)....(n-(n-1)). So all you need to do to get the super factorial is take the factorial of each component in the decomposition.

pseudo-code looks something like this

```
sp = 0 
for i = n to 1:
  sp = sp * factorial(i)
end for
return sp
```

Comment: you could also do the loop from 1 to n, doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive approach. 
Basically, in factorial you multiply n * fact(n-1). Here, we do fact(n) * superFact(n-1) as we need product of all factorials.

```
  int superfactorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
      return factorial(n);
    } else {
      return factorial(n) * superfactorial(n-1);
    }
  }


  int factorial(int n) {
    if(n == 0 || n == 1) {
      return n;
    } else {
      return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
  }
```